# Not being able to access an external link from digitalocean server

Tags: linux, server, digital-ocean

I am trying to access a particular external API resource from my digital ocean server. But I am getting connection timeout every time. The same resource can be accessed from my local machine but not from the server.

Comment: Where is the API located? If it is within you local network you will most likely not be able to access it from digital oceans servers. Can you ping the API resource?

Comment: It is the API  provided by the Payment Gateway I am using for my application. So, it is in the public domain.